# How to change the Type of Files

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi I am Writing the code in  the Java By Using TestNG Class, In the JAVA Eclipse all class is

storing with the extension as .java, But while coming the bin path in that folder Type is saving

as .CLASS, Now how can I change the type, I tried in different Ways but it is not working.

I am open with Note pad and Word Pad, Etc....File is opening, But the format and language is not in

the correct order?

Comment: why do you want to change the type of `.class` file?

Comment: Why you want to read compiled class file? Instead make changes to source and compile again. If you need to access this class file anyhow, use Java Decompiler tools.

Comment: Some confusion here.  A .java file is the input to the compiler and contains text that can be read by any editor.  A .class file is the output of a java compiler (javac program).  Its contents is byte code that can not be read(easily) in an editor.

Comment: NormR is correct.  Just don't worry about the .class file.  In some other location there is a .java file.  Modify that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the extension manually won't resolve your problem.

That is `.class`  file,containing a Java bytecode which can be executed on jvm,hich humans can't read it.

Just decompile it.Use some decompiler.

Comment: What exactly you want to do

Comment: I need to open the files which are located in the Bin Folder. Actually That files are saved with the Extension as a .class. Now I need to open that files. How?

Comment: you said `File is opening, But the format and language is not in

the correct order?`  That is true.To read it,you have to decompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a decompiler JdGui to open .class files

You can download it from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/JD-GUI.shtml).